# SQL merge data from table by reading dates array in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a query to get the day price of an asset and it's benchmark. The catch is that the benchmark to which the asset is compared may change over time. Fortunately, there is a table that stores the date the benchmark changed and to which benchmark it changed, as in the following example:

```
+-------+-----------+------------+
 | Asset | Benchmark | Date       |
 | A1    | B1        | 2015-01-01 |
 | A1    | B2        | 2015-05-07 |
 | A1    | B3        | 2015-09-03 |
 | A1    | B4        | 2075-12-31 |
 | A1    | B1        | 2075-12-31 |
 | A2    | B4        | 2014-05-07 |
 | A2    | B2        | 2075-12-31 |
 +-------+-----------+------------+
```

Where the Date field shows the date until which the benchmark would be correct.

Also, I have a table with the prices per date of each benchmark, as in the following table:

```
+------------+-----------+-------+
| Date       | Benchmark | Price |
| 2014-05-07 | B1        | 1000  |
| 2014-05-07 | B2        | 1200  |
| 2014-05-07 | B3        | 1050  |
| 2014-05-07 | B4        | 900   |
| ...        | ...       | ...   |
| 2015-01-01 | B1        | 1500  |
| 2015-01-01 | B2        | 1550  |
| 2015-01-01 | B3        | 1450  |
| 2015-01-01 | B4        | 1600  |
| ...        | ...       | ...   |
+------------+-----------+-------+
```

What I wish to do, is to join the benchmarks accordingly by date section to create a "single" benchmark. I would then join this to another table containing the asset price per day. For example, I would need to create a benchmark for asset A1 by obtaining the prices of benchmark B1 from the first date registered for A1 until 2015-01-01, then the prices from B2 from 2015-01-02 until 2015-05-07, then the prices from B3 2015-05-08 until 2015-09-03, and finally the prices of B4 from 2015-09-04 onwards.

The other problem with this is that the dataset must be continuous. By this I mean that when the benchmark is changed, the prices should be adjusted in such a way that the last day of the previous benchmark is equal to that same day in the new benchmark and then keep the same proportional growth from then on (by this I mean that Price(n)/Price(n+1) should remain the same after this adjustment).

The expected output would be only the Date and Price columns of the following table. The benchmark column is just for clarification purposes:

```
+------------+-------+-----------+
|    Date    | Price | Benchmark |
+------------+-------+-----------+
| 2014-05-07 | 1000  | B1        |
| 2014-05-08 | 1010  | B1        |
| ...        | ...   | ...       |
| 2015-01-01 | 1500  | B1        |
| 2015-01-02 | 1505  | B2        |
| 2015-01-03 | 1510  | B2        |
| ...        | ...   | ...       |
| 2015-05-06 | 1700  | B2        |
| 2015-05-07 | 1704  | B2        |
| 2015-05-08 | 1708  | B3        |
| 2015-05-09 | 1710  | B3        |
| ...        | ...   | ...       |
| 2015-09-02 | 2000  | B3        |
| 2015-09-03 | 1998  | B3        |
| 2015-09-04 | 2002  | B4        |
| ...        | ...   | ...       |
+------------+-------+-----------+
```

Can this all be done within a SQL query? Or should I turn to do this by code?

Comment: The 1st part is definitely doable. However, I do not understand the continuous bit.

Comment: Hello @Shadow, I'll try to explain in a clearer way. The data shows values of benchmarks for every date. These values are used to compare the value of the asset for each date. The real interest here is to show the daily change on the values, so the value for the benchmark itself does not really matter. This said, when a benchmark is changed for a given asset, the asset should not "perceive" this change. In other words:

Comment: Let's say benchmark A has values 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150 and benchmark B has values 200, 220, 240, 260, 280 for days 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. If the asset changes from A to B in day 3, I do not wish to compare it to [100, 110, 120, 260, 280], but rather to [100, 110, 120, (260 * (120/240)), (280 * (120/240))] @Shadow

Comment: Kind of got it. You can probably do this in mysql in a single query using session variables. However, if multiple users use the same db connection (session), then the same query run multiple times may interfere with each other.

Comment: @Shadow Thank you for your response. I will start studying about these session variables. Is there any kind of recommended material for this?

Comment: Lot of SO answers use them. Search for running total or cumulative sum, that is the kind of logic you will need here as well.